# Event registrant cancel/transfer error - getFieldValue failed - in SelfSvcUpdate.php

Tags: civievent, error

Here is backtrace:

```
0   CRM_Core_DAO::getFieldValue('CRM_Event_DAO_Ev…', null, 'title') /home/bbcadmin2016/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/SelfSvcUpdate.php:132
1   CRM_Event_Form_SelfSvcUpdate->preProcess()  /home/bbcadmin2016/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:602
2   CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()  /home/bbcadmin2016/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php:76
3   CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Event_Form_SelfSvcUpdate), 'display') /home/bbcadmin2016/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203
4   HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Event_Form_SelfSvcUpdate), 'display')  /home/bbcadmin2016/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103
5   HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle('display')  /home/bbcadmin2016/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php:347
6   CRM_Core_Controller->run()  /home/bbcadmin2016/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php:98
7   CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run('CRM_Event_Form_S…', 'Self-service Reg…', Array) /home/bbcadmin2016/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:285
8   CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array) /home/bbcadmin2016/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:68
9   CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array) /home/bbcadmin2016/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36
10  CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)  /home/bbcadmin2016/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1644
11  CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke() /home/bbcadmin2016/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.basepage.php:352
12  CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Basepage->basepage_handler(Object(WP))    /home/bbcadmin2016/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:287
13  WP_Hook->apply_filters(null, Array) /home/bbcadmin2016/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:311
14  WP_Hook->do_action(Array)   /home/bbcadmin2016/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:544
15  do_action_ref_array('wp', Array)    /home/bbcadmin2016/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php:758
16  WP->main('')    /home/bbcadmin2016/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:1285
17  wp()    /home/bbcadmin2016/public_html/wp-blog-header.php:16
18  require('/home/bbcadmin20…')    /home/bbcadmin2016/public_html/index.php:17
19  {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have pid supplied as param in cancel/transfer url? Does the requested participant has event id attached? Does this error is consistent?

Comment: The pid's are included in the cancel/transfer url, and the error is consistent; I believe that the answer to your middle question is yes.

It was suggested by a CivicCRM contributor that this issue might be a breaking change in CiviCRM WP v5.29 and 5.30.0 but I can't confirm that it's true as I haven't seen any posts referring to this.

Comment: I should have indicated that this installation is CiviCRM v5.30.0 on WP 5.5.1